# Is the Bill Of Sale required for deregistration?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, aircraft-registration

Is the Bill Of Sale required for deregistration?

What are the FAA and EASA regulations applicable?

Comment: I really mean de-registration not re-registration. I know that the BOS is required for re-registration but is it required for de-registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US you don't need a bill of sale because the aircraft may not have been sold. The [FAA's definition](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/definitions.aspx) says:

> **Deregistered Aircraft** An aircraft that has been removed from the U.S. Civil Aircraft Register at the owner's request. Aircraft are
>   generally removed for the following reasons: exported, destroyed,
>   salvaged, dismantled, or permanently retired from service.

There would be no bill of sale for a destroyed aircraft, for example.

If you're asking about handling the FAA registration when you sell an aircraft, according to [AOPA's guide](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/aircraft-and-ownership/selling-an-aircraft) you have to sign and return the current registration certificate, and the FAA will issue a new one to the buyer.